# How to fix the issue of saving input data using node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Developing a mongoose database and I would like some support with the issue I have encountered. I followed the tutorial step by step carefully and I cannot see where I am going wrong

I have installed the **“var bodyParser=require(‘body-parser’)** module within app.js.  **I would like to save the data that is inputted within the form in the register view.**  So within the users.js, I have declared the routers for the register view and router. post. the code is below 
When I go to test out the name field form in the register view. I do not see the input passed through the terminal. **I receive this error  below**

```
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
at C:\Users\Sue\myCommunityFinal2Mongoose\app.js:78:8
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
(C:\Users\Sue\myCommunityFinal2Mongoose\node_modules\express
\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Users.js

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('register');
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var hbs = require('hbs');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


app.use(expressValidator({
errorFormatter: function (pram, msg, value) {
var namespace = pram.split('.')
, root = namespace.shift()
, formParam = root;

while (namespace.length) {
  fornmParam += '[' + namespace.shift()

}
return {
  param: formParam,
  msg: msg,
  value: value
};
```

}
}));

I went to the app.js file and noticed that I missed out the message validation so I included the code below

```
app.use(require('connect-flash') ());
app.use(function (req,res,next) {
res.locals.message= require('express-message')(req,res);
next();
});
```

When I run the code I get the error express-message module missing. So I npm install “ express-message “ but get the error “ code e404, the express module is not found".

Not to sure what to do next, **my expected result is to be able to input data into the fields without no error so I can model this data in a MongoDB database.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that express is not installed correctly on your machine.

```
    run `npm cache clean` and try again
```

If that does not work run `npm install @types/express`

Comment: tried steps above not working, is there any other options?